# The role of PCA (Principal Component Analysis) in recording neurons

Tags: neuroscience, neuron, signal-processing, neural-engineering

I am reviewing the recording methods from an experiment that tracked neuronal activity on the prefrontal cortex of a monkey.

From the method description in [Nieder, Andreas, David J. Freedman, and Earl K. Miller. "Representation of the quantity of visual items in the primate prefrontal cortex." Science 297.5587 (2002): 1708-1711](http://monkeylogic.uchicago.edu/old/niederScience2002.pdf).:

> Recordings were made from three hemispheres of the PFC [prefrontal cortex] of two adult rhesus monkeys. [...] Arrays of eight to twelve tungsten microelectrodes (FHC) were inserted using a grid (Crist Instruments) with 1-mm spacing. [...] Neurons were selected at random; no attempt was made to search for task-related activity. Waveform separation was performed off-line applying principal component analysis (Plexon Systems).

Does anyone know what PCA (Principal Component Analysis) is exactly used for here? My guess would be that it is used to cluster "significant" waveforms, i.e. to identify neurons. But I could not really find reliable resources online.

The role is unfortunately not included somewhere in the paper quoted :(

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. 1) Please always define abbreviations and acronyms before using them (you use two PCA and PFC). 2) When you include a quotation you must include the citation. 3) The role should be included somewhere in the paper you quote — please don't expect us to read and interpret papers for you. 4) Please don't include "thanks" and "signatures" in you posts. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] and then the section on ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for details about expectations for users and their questions.

Comment: PCA is the simplest way to perform [spike sorting](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Spike_sorting), which is necessary when the experimenter has no way of verifying that recordings are coming from single neurons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like vkehayas mentions in a comment, they're using it for spike sorting, as you've guessed. This involves both identifying signals from putative neurons (vs noise) and separating different source neurons, when possible.

[Plexon's website](https://plexon.com/products/offline-sorter/#1428832) mentions "Manual cluster selection in 3D feature space using principal component projections, voltage slices in time, or more than 20 other waveform features such as peak, valley, full-width at half maximum, etc." for their software.

There are many, many different ways to sort spikes, some supervised some unsupervised, some using PCA, some using the original waveforms, some using other types of decomposition.

David Redish's [MClust](https://redishlab.umn.edu/mclust) is one example [which is open source](https://github.com/adredish/MClust-Spike-Sorting-Toolbox) if you'd like to look at some similar software; I assume Plexon's is proprietary but they'll be using similar approaches.